# Странное поведение условия If. Unity3d

Tags: unity3d

Есть простой код, который подключен к кнопке.

```
 public void Inc()
    {
        if (x < 5)
        {
            x++;
            Debug.Log(x);
        }

        Debug.Log("Done");
    }
```

По идее, я ожидаю, что после пяти нажатий на кнопку, появится сообщение Done. Но Done, появляется после каждого увеличения X на 1 единицу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Простите, но оператор if не имеет отношения к циклу. Это ветвление.

Comment: Если быть совсем точным, то это условие) Но суть вопроса от этого не меняется. Почему Done отображается раньше, чем условие выполняется?

Comment: Почему раньше? Первая строка в логах: 1. Вторая строка - Done. И т.д.
Все работает корректно. Или я чего-то упускаю?

Comment: В словах условие выглядит так: Если X меньше чем 5, то увеличиваем Х на 1, а затем выводим в консоль сообщение со значением Х.
Т.е. Done должна появиться, если X больше, чем 5.

Comment: Вывод, который я ожидаю:
1
2
3
4
5
Done

Comment: Тогда Вам просто необходим оператор else. Код в ответ вставил, сейчас отредактирую с описанием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Inc()
{
    if (x < 5)
    {
        x++;
        Debug.Log(x);
    }
    else
        Debug.Log("Done");
}
```

Метод Inc() по Вашему коду всегда выводит в лог сообщение "Done", поскольку, если условие (x < 5) верно, то не предусмотрено выхода. Поэтому нужно либо после if использовать else, либо после Debug.Log(x) использовать return.

Только сейчас обратил внимание на "пять нажатий". В таком случае после проверки x<5 следует сделать еще проверку на равенство 5. Вот тогда за одно выполнение Inc() будет возможен и инкремент и вывод сообщения, что задача выполнена.

```
if (x < 5)
{
    x++;
    Debug.Log(x);
}

if (x == 5)
    Debug.Log("Done");
```